# Need a code to count from one to ten in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need a simple code that can count from 1 -10 in javascript

I have tried :

```
function countToTen() {
    console.log("1");
    console.log("2");
    console.log("3");
    console.log("4");
    console.log("5");
    console.log("6");
    console.log("7");
    console.log("8");
    console.log("9");
    console.log ("10");
}

return countToTen;
```

but I guess this is wrong. Can anyone help please?

Comment: SEarch for a `for `loop.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a simple [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Per your comment, you can wrap this in a function as well:

```
function countToTen() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

countToTen(); // Will write 1-10 to your console
```

Comment: Sorry it has to have a function too I forgot. How do I add a function for example test function

Comment: @user3229531 - You should be able to incorporate a for loop into a function; doing so is very basic, and learning how to do so is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest function that uses for loops to count from 1-10 would look like as below.

```
function count() {
  for (number = 1; number <= 10; number++) {
    console.log(number);
  }
}
count();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to everyone in this situation to **take a look at** https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for to realize the possibilities of a 'For Loop'.

You can try 2 different methods. Remember that using **let** instead of **var** can be useful for you:

**1. While**

```
let i = 10; 
while (i <= 10) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

**2. For**

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

**3. Extra:** you can try to wrap your code in a function and reuse it later on.

```
function countNumbers() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

(Remember to invoke it afterward, like:)

```
countNumbers();
```

If you want to start counting from 1, just assign 1 instead of 0 to 'i'.

Hope this helps. I know I'm late but I just wanted to make sure that this could be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The **for loop** is a fundamental component of javascript. You might want to check out http://jstherightway.org/ for a good primer.

For this question, the code would look like;

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [while loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp):

```
    function countToTen(){
        var i = 1;
        while(i <=10){
            console.log(i);
            i++;
        }

    }
    countToTen() // function call
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason why you'd use a `while` over a `for` in this situation?

Comment: while loops are generally faster than for loops. Although a well formatted for loop is nearly as fast as a while loop in modern JS engines.

Comment: Ok interesting, I did not know about the speed difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using loops

**1. For**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
console.log(i);
}
```

**2. While**

```
var i = 1;
while(i <= 10){    
   console.log(i);
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let i=0;while(i++ < 10) console.log(i)`

I swear there's a shorter way to do this using something along the lines of

`Array(10).map(...)` but maybe I'm low on coffee this morning.

THAT SAID I strongly recommend using syntactically friendly code like @jterry used, you'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an imperative language and the answers here are pretty much great for JavaScript. Just for fun here is a functional way to do it. Its the perfect one liner.

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map((n) => console.log(n))
```